# Getting the Average Height of a Binary Search Tree

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I have come to a problem statement where the tree is in the form:

```
     4
  2     6
1   3 5   7
```

It said that the average height is 1.4285715

Based from what I know, the average height of a tree is the sum of height of each node divided by the total number of nodes. However I am getting a different result. I need a hint on how the value 1.4285715 is computed.

Comment: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2762/what-is-the-average-height-of-a-binary-tree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use your formula ans set root depth to 0: `(0 + 1 + 1 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2) / 7 = 10 / 7 = 1.4285715`.

Answer (score 4):

The root node typically isn't included in the height, though it is included when counting the  nodes. So, we have two nodes of height 1 and four nodes of height 2:

```
(2 * 1) + (4 * 2) = 10
10 / 7            = 1.4285714286
```

Read more at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree

Answer (score 4):

```
     4        // 0
  2     6     // 1
1   3 5   7   // 2

(0 + 1 + 1 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2) / 7 = 1.4285715
```